# Call to undefined function session_name()

Tags: php, session, yii

Hope someone can help me with this problem. I keep getting this error message:
`Call to undefined function session_name() in /var/www/yii1.1.14/framework/web/CHttpSession.php on line 197`.

This is the `session` part from `main.php`:

```
'session' => array(
    'sessionName' => 'Site Session',
    'class' => 'CHttpSession',
    'autoStart' => true
```

),

Comment: Theres no function in there, so this cant be the error. Can you give us the lines where the error actually occurs?

Comment: It occures when I try to access `Yii::app()->user` or `Yii::app()->session`, e.g. `$user = Yii::app()->user;`

Comment: i had this error because of absent mindness, i uses `sesion_name` versus `session_name` with double `ss`